# Given an array A, concatenate it with an array B inside an object of React useState

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

- I am implementing infinite scroll in React, and I have to call backend API to get the content for the next page. However, I have set the useState as an object. And want to update the array inside the object.
- I know this can be easily solved by setting results as an useState and making additional useState for "next" and "previous"; however, I want to find how to solve this with the current condition.
- Please also suggest which one will be an optimal way to go (one useState<object(Custom interface)> or three useState for "result", "next" and "previous" individually)

I have a React useState hook initialized with the data given below

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": 2,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
   {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'test1'
   },
   {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'test2'
   }

   ]
}
```

and the new data I get is of the form

```
data = {
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": 1,
    "results": [
   {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'test3'
   },
   {
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'test4'
   }

   ]
}
```

How can I concatenate two array and update the state, to have a result something like this

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": 1,
    "results": [
   {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'test1'
   },
   {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'test2'
   },
   {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'test3'
   },
   {
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'test4'
   }

   ]
}
```

Comment: So to clarify, you are trying to keep the data in the `results` array but update the `count`, `next`, and `previous` values and append the new data to the `results` array?

Comment: Yes @GianinaSkarlett that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your state variable was named `state`, you would do something like this:

```
setState({
  ...state, 
  next: null, 
  previous: 1, 
  results: [
    ...state.results, 
    {
      'id': 3,
      'name': 'test3'
    },
    {
      'id': 4,
      'name': 'test4'
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you @jordanjlatimer my major mistake was not using spread operator for data

```
setState({
  ...state, 
  next: null, 
  previous: 1, 
  results: [
    ...state.results, 
    ...data
   
  ]
})
```

Comment: If you found my answer useful, upvote it and/or make it the accepted answer.